# Page Layout does not appear in the page layouts list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a feature that deploys a few site columns, a content type (inheriting from Page Publishing Content Type) and a page layout based on my content type.

Everything is fine on two tests, performed on different servers, but on the third server, although the feature is being activated correctly and I can see the site columns, content types and the page layout in the galleries, I cannot create a new page based on my page layout because the page layout does not appear in the list of available page layouts.

On all tests I have used the administrator account.

Does anybody have any thoughts on possible reasons for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the publish status of the page layout in the server that does not work?

Comment: Yes, the page layout appears as approved in the gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

What actually happened is that the page layout was, for some reason, deployed as a Master page and not as a Page Layout. The admin has manually changed this and now it works.

Answer (score 15):

Did you have a look at the "Page layouts and site templates" page under Site Settings? On this page you can enable an option that limits the available page layouts to a specified list of page layouts.

I have worked on a project where we needed to limit the page layouts available on a custom site definition. We implemented this in a feature, that enabled the "limited page layouts" option and populated the list of available page layouts upon activation.

If this is the issue you are having you could simply turn off this option in the web interface or add the new page layouts manually, but you could also consider implementing a feature receiver that automatically adds your custom page layouts to the list of available layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an educated guess but check to see if the Page Layout is waiting to be checked-in or approved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the path for the layout was wrong so the layout itself ended up in a different location, when I corrected that i was able to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had added files manually and it did not appear. 
When I edited properties of that layout page from UI and saved it, it appeared.